# Liquid Template - Unable To Modify Jekyll Carousel Script

Tags: html, templates, jekyll, liquid, liquid-template

I'm using the Jekyll framework and using the official Carousel script from their website (https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/slider/) and I'm struggling to figure out how to make it possible to pass a name to the carousel.html script so that I can setup multiple carousels using the same script. My goal is to be able to just use:

```
 {% include carousel.html name="CatImages" height="20" unit="%" duration="7" %}
```

and it should be able to simply receive the images from a carousel.yml file that looks similar to: `

```
CatImages: 
  - /assets/img/cat1.png
  - /assets/img/cat2.png
```

I've tried to append the string to the variable name, which works but gives me a slightly different output - one that I can't figure out the type of. The resulting variable coming from

```
{{site.data.carousel.{{ include.name }}}}
```

returns `{"CatImages"=>["/assets/img/cat1.png", "/assets/img/cat2.png"]}` and when running through the for loops it returns the image paths as one whole string. For example, this:

```
 {% for item in images %}
            {{item}}           
 {% endfor %}
```

returns:

```
images/assets/img/cat1.png/assets/img/cat2.png
```

But overall, I don't understand what the variable is and I can't figure it out from googling. I'm new to Liquid templates, but for the life of me I can't figure out what the {""=>["",""]} notation is.

Any pointers or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you call `{{ include.name }}` inside your `for` loop? It should return "CatImages." Does it not?

Comment: It does! It outputs "CatImages", which is great and is how I'm able to get the (strange) type that outputs  `{"CatImages"=>["/assets/img/cat1.png", "/assets/img/cat2.png"]}`. Perhaps `{{site.data.carousel.{{ include.name }}}}` isn't the correct way to obtain the list of image paths?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It's pretty obvious now and I've learned a ton on the way (like I'm actually using Liquid and not Django).

My issues was that I was trying to do:

`{{site.data.carousel.{{ include.name }}}}`

But instead all I had to do was:

`{{site.data.carousel[include.name]}}`